# How to plugin custom WidgetsService in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I need to create a custom WidgetsService implementation and use that instead of the default Orchard implementation.  I assume I need to work with autofac to register my own implementation but not sure on the details.  Could you help with step-by-step instructions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you just need to use the OrchardSuppressDependency attribute.